# Generics - how to define a method that takes only classes that implement a particular interface

Tags: java, generics

I've got a method that currently looks like this:

```
public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz) {

   return  applicationContext.getBean(clazz);
}
```

At the moment it can take any type of class. I want to limit that (at compile time) so that it can only allow a limited set of classes.

So I'm thinking I can define an interface like this:

```
public interface GettableBean<T>  {}
```

and change the code to this (which looks horrid with a cast):

```
public static <T> T getBean(GettableBean<T> clazz) {

   return (T) applicationContext.getBean(clazz.getClass());
}
```

and what's more when I try and call it using a class that implements GettableBean

```
public class MyClass implements GettableBean<MyClass>
```

I get a compile error:

> Error:(119, 27) java: method getBean in class BeanLocator cannot be applied to given types;
>     required: GettableBean
>     found: java.lang.Class
>     reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
>       (argument mismatch; java.lang.Class cannot be converted to GettableBean)

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Aren't you overthinking this? `public static GettableBean getBean(GettableBean clazz) {` should work well enough.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you think `GettableBean` needs to be parameterized. It's just a [marker interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern).

Remove the redundant generic type parameter and add a constraint to the `getBean` method.

```
public interface GettableBean  {}

public class MyClass implements GettableBean {}

public static <T extends GettableBean> T getBean(Class<T> clazz) {}
```

The name of this parameter should have been your clue that what you were trying was not really the right approach:

```
public static <T> T getBean (GettableBean<T> clazz)
```

A `GettableBean` is not a class. It's an instance. It should be called `gettableBean`. When you rename that, it becomes more clear that you're passing an instance only pretty much immediately disregard everything about the instance.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Re GettableBean  being parameterized, that's why I couldn't get it to work and you could :-) More learning needed on my part...

Comment: @PaulNUK The redundancy would not ordinarily be a problem (IDEs will warn you "You declared this `T` thing and never used it" -- but it's "only a *warning*" right?), however due to type erasure, `Class` and generic type parameters don't really inter-op in a way that is idiomatic for most people, so things get simpler when it is removed

Answer (score 0):

**ONE:**

The error message originates in the return statement: `clazz.getClass()` returns a `Class<?>`. You try to cast it to `T`. To successfully do so `Class` would have to be an implementation or extension of `T`. You could declare that by

```
public static <T super Class<?>> T getBean(...) ...
```

But that's most likely not what you want.

**TWO**

Actually from my understanding what you want is to allow only `Class` parameters for implementations of `GettableBean<?>`. That should look like this:

```
public static <T> T getBean(Class<? extends GettableBean<T>> clazz) {

   return  applicationContext.getBean(clazz);
}
```